# AWT: I am trying to learn Java and was unable to understand the following program

Tags: java, object, canvas, components, awt

1. What is "new MyCanvas()" in f.add(new MyCanvas());
2. How did we get the oval even though the paint() method is not called either in CanvasExample class constructor or in the main() method
3. What is new CanvasExample() in the main() method

---

```
import java.awt.*;

public class CanvasExample {  
    public CanvasExample() {  
        Frame f = new Frame("Canvas Example");  
        f.add(new MyCanvas());  
        f.setLayout(null);  
        f.setSize(400, 400);  
        f.setVisible(true);  
    }  

    public static void main(String args[]) {  
        new CanvasExample();
    }  
}  

class MyCanvas extends Canvas {  
    public MyCanvas() {  
        setBackground (Color.GRAY);  
        setSize(300, 200);  
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){  
        g.setColor(Color.red);  
        g.fillOval(75, 75, 150, 75);  
    } 
}
```

Please explain

Comment: `new` is used for creating an object of a class in java. `paint()` looks like a callback. google these terms to learn more.

Comment: @NicholasK Thanks .... I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's an instance of `Canvas` class. In Java `new` is a keyword used to create an object (an instance of given class). That being said - `new Canvas()` creates new instance of `Canvas` class. Brackets after class name indicate constructor - block of code that is being called when you wan to create an object of given type.
2. You got oval because the `paint` method **was called**. It just wasn't called explicitly from your code. As you can read in [this tutorial article published by Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callback), the `paint` method will be always triggerred as so called "callback mechanism". This method belongs to `Container` class. I suggest reading [docs about it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#paint(java.awt.Graphics)). The `paint` method in `MyCanvas` class overrides the `paint` method from `Canvas`. When extending `Canvas` class and overriding `paint` method you should always call the super method at the beginning of your method. You can read why in the links I have already included in this point.
3. As in point #1 - `new CanvasExample()` creates new instance of `MyCanvas` class. More specifically, it calls constructor (`public CanvasExample() { ... }`). In code you presented, constructor of CanvasExample creates new object of type `Frame` and calls some of it's methods. One of these methods is `add` and it was inherited by class `Frame` from its the superclass - `Container`.
   As [Java awt API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.awt.Component)) explains, the `add` method:

   > appends the specified component to the end of this container.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you will understand :D 
at first it call `public static void main(String args[])`
then `main` make new instance of class `CanvasExample` and call its constructor`CanvasExample()`
that constructor make new instance of class `Frame` named "f" and call constructor of class `Frame` it set title of that frame to "Canvas Example"
in next row of constructor`CanvasExample()` it make and add new instance of class `MyCanvas` to instance of `Frame` named "f"
third row of constructor`CanvasExample()` it just set Layout of "f" to `null`
fourth row of constructor`CanvasExample()` it set size of "f" to 400x400
fifth row of constructor`CanvasExample()` it just show "f" to screen (so you can see it)
and end of constructor`CanvasExample()` it get back to `main`
when creating new instance of class `MyCanvas` is called constructor of it and that constructor set background of it to "Color.GRAY" and size of it to 300x200 and all of `MyCanvas()` constructor

everytime when "f" needs to be rendered again it call method `paint(Graphics g)` of instance of class `MyCanvas` bit that instance is smaller than "f" so you can see white behind 
that white is background of "f"

I think thats all what you ask for.
have a nice day

Comment: shouldnt the instance have a variable? eg. CanvasExample c = new CanvasExample